# Is there a way to turn on (not wake up) a laptop with the lid closed and without opening the lid?

Tags: productivity, energy-saving, lid

I want to know if there's a way to turn on (not wake up) my laptop without opening the lid. Not wake up, turn on.

I've seen this type of question being asked all the time, but it always ends up being answered with the wake up configuration, which doesn't necessarily gives a response to what I'm asking.

I have a Huawei Matebook D15 with Windows 11, and mostly use it with the lid closed and an external monitor, and even though the sleep and hibernate functions save energy, I prefer to know if there's a software configuration or an external device (that doesn't require making holes on the case) that allows to turn it on.

Comment: Generally yes.  Put the laptop in a dock and turn it on at the dock. Works fine.

Comment: So you want to know how to turn on your laptop without opening the lid? Is that what this is all about?

Comment: You don't have to make a new hole to run a switch outside the case -- use an existing one.

Comment: You say not wake up you did not say not "wake on lan" because if you tell the OS to do nothing when the lid is closed, sleep options wise, enable WOL with the network adapter properties to allow wake on lan magic packet, and you also disable hibernation i.e. `powercfg hibernate off`, then you can send UPD port 7 or 9 WOL magic packet to power it up if it's powered off not hibernated or in sleep mode remotely from another machine by sending the mac address the broadcast UDP port 7 or 9 magic packet to start it up if it's powered off.

Comment: `turn on (not wake up)` .. you need to look into more specificity to your own question.. the [ACPI specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACPI) essentially provides two "off" states.  G2?  Possibly.   .. G3?  No way in hell.  Even G2 is unlikely in your situation and depends on the firmware to support waking from a device while OFF.  You also did not mention WHAT you are trying to use to power it on with?

Comment: @John The only type of docks I've seen that lets you power on your laptop are the Lenovo Thinkpad Ultradock Stations (the old models). Other than that, I haven't found any dock that has a power button for turning on laptops (some have a power button but it's for turning on the dock itself). If you know of any particular dock that does that, I would really appreciate the name and/or brand so I can google it and see if I can buy one

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Yeah. That's exactly it. More specifically, how can I power on a fully turned off laptop. That means one that's not on sleep or hibernation mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way in your case is to set in bios to "power on" when AC connected (if such option is available).  So in order to power on, just unplug the docking cable and plug in back (If the dock is supplying the power to laptop).  The laptop will detect the power connected and switch on accordingly.

I have been looking for this and there is no solution.  Once upon a time there is a laptop with power button at the side where user can slide it to switch on, but no longer exists nowadays.  I ended up using business laptop and use proprietary dock to switch on the laptop.  There is a power-on button which only works with certain product range of that brand.